# Installed Font in OS X is not available

Tags: macos, fonts, office-for-mac, microsoft-word-2011

I've installed a font on an OS X box, and it's enabled and shows in TextEdit, but for some reason, it will not show in Word 2011.

Any pointers as to why it shows in some apps, and not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Office for Mac [seems to have problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295062) with some third party fonts.

The solution steps outlined by Microsoft would include:

> - Restart your computer, and then test the font again. Some installations are not complete until the computer is restarted. This also makes sure that all applications are restarted after the installation.
> - Clear the font caches. To do this, quit all Microsoft Office applications. On the **Home** menu, click **Go**. Open the Library\Preferences\Microsoft\Office 2008 (or 2011) folder, and then click the Office Font Cache 12 for Office 2008 file or the Office Font Cache 2011 file.
> - Create a new user account to see whether the problem is associated with an existing user account.

I personally would try to uninstall the font, then clear the font caches, and try it again. There are also some [other weird issues](http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/421299-solved-fonts-not-showing-up.html) that involve printers, but that's not likely to be the problem in your case.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer, and the edits! I appreciate the time you put in. Knowing this info has helped reassure me that I'm not crazy, and I was hitting a brick wall! Thanks